# Selenium PhantomJS webdriver doesn't click

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

This code works perfectly using firefox webdriver. But with PhantomJS it doesn't click the desired javascript links.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://justbet.co.ke/index.php?option=com_justbet&league=1539&Itemid=123")
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='optionmore']")
for more in range(0, len(options)):
        options[more].click()
        sleep(3)
```

Comment: If I compare the page source for both results, they are different. With firefox, the source contains the parts activated by clicking the javascript link, while with phantomjs it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works if you select the *a* tags inside the *optionmore* classes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://justbet.co.ke/index.php?option=com_justbet&league=1539&Itemid=123")
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='optionmore']/a")
print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='suboption ']"))
for opt in options:
    opt.click()
print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='suboption ']"))
```

Running the code above:

```
In [27]: from selenium import webdriver

In [28]: driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()    
In [29]: driver.get("http://justbet.co.ke/index.php?option=com_justbet&league=1539&Itemid=123")    
In [30]: options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='optionmore']/a")    
In [31]: print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='suboption ']")))
0

In [32]: for opt in options:
   ....:         opt.click()
   ....:     

In [33]: print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='suboption ']")))
270
```

You get all the td's with the data you want.